# MySQL Query makes server very slow

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have this view that makes my MySQL server run really slow, even breaks connection. Has anyone have an idea why?

```
select 
u1.`ID` AS `ID`,
u1.`post_date` AS `post_date`,
u1.`processed` AS `processed`,
m1.`meta_value` AS `from`,
m2.`meta_value` AS `subject`
from `wp`.`wp_posts` u1
JOIN `wp`.`wp_postmeta` m1 ON (m1.`meta_key` = '_from_name')
JOIN `wp`.`wp_postmeta` m2 ON (m2.`meta_key` = '_subject')
where (u1.`post_type` = 'flamingo_inbound' AND u1.processed = 0 )

union 

select 
u1.`ID` AS `ID`,
u1.`post_date` AS `post_date`,
u1.`processed` AS `processed`,
m1.`meta_value` AS `from`,
m2.`meta_value` AS `subject`
from `wp2`.`wp_posts` u1
JOIN `wp2`.`wp_postmeta` m1 ON (m1.`meta_key` = '_from_name')
JOIN `wp2`.`wp_postmeta` m2 ON (m2.`meta_key` = '_subject')
where (u1.`post_type` = 'flamingo_inbound'AND u1.processed = 0 )
order by `ID` desc
```

Comment: Why do you have same select query in both parts of the union? UNION is going to give back unique set of rows.

Comment: And why do you join without a join condition?

Comment: Because I want a view of the result of two databases, with the same structure. I will be adding more databases, as there all the data has to come from. These are different sites, that will handle support tickets in one desktop solution

Comment: You still need join conditions like `m1.post_id = u1.ID`. And you should probably use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, thank you... will try that.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, that worked! Thanks